# Is L1 cache missing in one of the CPUs ? (HP ProLiant server, dual Xeon E5-2620)

Tags: caching, cpu

I recently played around with `# wminfo` on a HP ProLiant DL380 Gen9 server (dual Xeon E5-2620). Something seems strange. It seems one of the CPUs is missing L1 cache :

```
# hwinfo --bios | grep -A 17 "Processor Info" | grep -e "Processor Info" -e Version -e "Cache:"
  Processor Info: #3
    Version: "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz"
    L2 Cache: #1
    L3 Cache: #2
  Processor Info: #7
    Version: "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz"
    L1 Cache: #4
    L2 Cache: #5
    L3 Cache: #6
```

The first CPU doesn't seem to have a L1 cache. Is this possible ? Can a CPU work without its L1 cache ?

Next command shows a #0 cache that doesn't seem to be used by any of the CPUs (#1 to #5 caches are referred to by the previous command output) :

```
# hwinfo --bios | grep -A 10 "Cache Info" | grep -e "Cache Info" -e Level -e "Current Size" -e "--"
  Cache Info: #0
    Level: L1
    Current Size: 384 kB
--
  Cache Info: #1
    Level: L2
    Current Size: 1536 kB
--
  Cache Info: #2
    Level: L3
    Current Size: 15360 kB
--
  Cache Info: #4
    Level: L1
    Current Size: 384 kB
--
  Cache Info: #5
    Level: L2
    Current Size: 1536 kB
--
  Cache Info: #6
    Level: L3
    Current Size: 15360 kB
```

The server works fine, I don't have any issue. Any idea what's going on ? Is one of the CPUs slowly dying ?

Comment: It's probably a bug in `hwinfo` (which doesn't even return cache information in my Arch) or your grepping. Try using a better source of information: `cpuid --leave 4` and `cpuid --leave 2`.

Comment: I don't think it'a a bug in hwinfo or my grepping, because I have a second server, same OS, same hwinfo version, and the same command returns all 3 cache levels on each processor. Only difference, the processors are not the same (one server is a DL380Gen8, the other a Gen9). The missing L1 cache is in Gen9.
There must be something else. I'll do some tests with cpuid to see if I can get more infos...

Comment: I just checked with cpuid, everything seems fine... Strange...